# How can I use a Javascript variable as href inside an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, anchor, href

I am setting up a system for pagination with similarly-named pages. I was able to set up a system that takes my original page's url and creates a "next" and "previous" link. However, these links are in the form of JS variables, and I don't know to insert them inside an anchor tag.

My current code is:

```js
function break_address(url_add) {
      var page = url_add.split("/").slice(-1);
    var num = url_add.split('page-')[1]; 
[1]; //next
  var numnext = parseInt(num)+1;
  var numprev = parseInt(num)-1;
  var nextpage = "https://MYCOMIC.neocities.org/page-" + numnext + ".html";
   var prevpage = "https://MYCOMIC.neocities.org/page-" + numprev + ".html";
   //this return is only so that I can make sure the new links were created correctly
    return [num, numnext,numprev,nextpage,prevpage]
 document.getElementById("next").setAttribute("href",nextpage);
}
//in the real code i am adding the current url with window.location.href instead
var url_add = "https://MYCOMIC.neocities.org/page-2.html"
console.log("Original address: "+url_add)
console.log(break_address(url_add))
```

```html
<!--the links are set to # right now because I don't know how to set them up. I originally tried setting them as <a id="next">link</a>, but this resulted in an un-clickable link.-->
<a href="#">
    <img src="previous.png" alt="PREVIOUS PAGE" style="height: 75px; width: 75px; padding-left 50px, padding-right: 50px;"></a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="next.png" alt="NEXT PAGE" style="height: 75px; width: 75px; padding-left 50px, padding-right: 50px;"></a>
```

In another similar question on here, someone suggested adding something along the lines of

```
document.getElementById("next").href = nextpage;
```

inside the script, and then recalling it by doing

```
<a id="nextpage">link</a>
```

However, when I tried to do this, the link could not be clicked.

I tried adding href back into the anchor tag`<a href="#" id="nextpage">link</a>`) but then the link goes to the same page I am already on.

What am I doing wrong? (note: the files linked to by the new generated urls do all exist.)

I know I can link the next and previous pages manually. I don't want this, I want code which can automatically link to the urls generated by the Javascript. Is this possible? How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way of using `anchor` tag:

```
<a href="yourPagePath/page-1.html">link</a>
```

Comment: Same comment as I made on the other answer--I don't want to manually put in the new links. The point of all the JavaScript was so that my code would automatically get the urls for the next and previous page no matter what page I started on, so that I can copy this code across all my comic pages. Is there no way to automatically use the new urls generated by the JS?

Answer (score 0):

> In another similar question on here, someone suggested adding something along the lines of: `document.getElementById("next").href = nextpage;`

From the html code you provided, it seems like you never specified an id on the `a` tag so so no element is retrieved.

However, another solution would be to just embed the path of the html file in the `a` tag's href like so:

`<a href="path_to_html_file/page-1.html">link</a>`

Comment: I did try to specify an ID on the `a` tag, like this: `<a id="nextpage">link</a>` but when I had this in my code, my links didn't work at all. I can't use `<a href="path/page-1.html">link</a>` because I want this code to be copy/pasted through ALL my pages, if I was just going to manually link the next and previous then I wouldn't have bothered with the JS. Is there not any way to automatically use my JS generated urls in the `a` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who tried to help, I ended up figuring it out with some help from someone I know IRL.
My final code looked like this:

```js
//takes my current page's url which is in the form path/page-#.html and splits off the #.html
function get_nextpage(url_add) {
      var page = url_add.split("/").slice(-1);
    var num = url_add.split('page-')[1]; 
[1];
//adds 1 to the number within the #.html, makes a new link which is "nextpage"
  var numnext = parseInt(num)+1;
  var nextpage = "https://MYCOMIC.neocities.org/page-" + numnext + ".html";
  return nextpage;
}
//same but for previous page
function get_prevpage(url_add) {
      var page = url_add.split("/").slice(-1);
    var num = url_add.split('page-')[1]; 
[1];
  var numprev = parseInt(num)-1;
  var prevpage = "https://MYCOMIC.neocities.org/page-" + numprev + ".html";
  return prevpage;
}
//function which uses the new url whenever my links are clicked
window.onload = function(e) {
  var url_add = window.location.href;
  var nextpage = get_nextpage(url_add);
  var prevpage = get_prevpage(url_add);
  document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {
    this.href = nextpage;
    console.log(this.href);
  };
  document.getElementById("prev").onclick = function() {
    this.href = prevpage;
    console.log(this.href);
  };
}();
```

```html
<a class="button" id="prev" href="#">
    <img src="previous.png" alt="PREVIOUS PAGE" style="height: 75px; width: 75px; padding-left 50px, padding-right: 50px;"></a>
<a class="button" id="next" href="#" >
    <img src="next.png" alt="NEXT PAGE" style="height: 75px; width: 75px; padding-left 50px, padding-right: 50px;"></a>
```

It might be a bit more complicated than ideal but it works!